# WPF Databinding vs Programmatically generating controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My underlying data structure consists of a hierarchy of objects that are built upon a common abstract class:

```
public abstract class model {
   public string name {get;};
   public string type {get;};
}

public class A:model {
   public int val1 {get; set;}; 
}

public class B:model {
   public int val2 {get; set;}; 
}

public class C:B {
   public Dictionary<string, int> extra_props; 
}
```

My goal is to create a UI that upon object selection, is able to dynamically preview but also be able to modify the object's underlying properties.

I'm an absolute noob regarding WPF, so I have no idea what its full capabilities are. For now regarding the single value properties, I have found my way to use Databinding to bind the properties to the UI elements. It works like a charm for showing and also modifying the values.

```
<GroupBox x:Name="InfoBox" Header="Object Information">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="41*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <TextBlock>Name:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <TextBlock>Type:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding type}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <TextBlock>Material Name:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding val1}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

**Problem 1:**
When an object of type `B` is bound, property `val1` doesn't exist and I'm getting some BindingErrors in the debug output. These cause no problem during execution at all, but I have found no way of catching them and returning a default value or something.

The only way that I have thought of for solving this issue is to add all the desired properties in the abstract class so that they all exist on all derived classes with some null values or something, but this doesn't feel right at all.

**Problem 2:**
For more complex classes like `C`, I want to dynamically generate the UI based on a set/list of properties of the class. For now I have absolutely no idea how to do it with databinding, except for adding them all one by one in the XML and working around the issues of problem 1.

The most viable solution that I thought of is to programmatically generate a Control and add it to the main window with textboxes and inputs for the class properties that I need, and again programmatically hopefully be able to bind the object to the control so that the values are read/set appropriately. Obviously this method would resolve problem 1 as well.

I'm not even sure if this solution is possible or not, but in any case I need recommendations and advice on mainly if there is a way to resolve my issues with data-binding or if I should go with with programmatically updating the UI (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a noob you're doing well so far :) There's actually a very simple solution to both of these problems: DataTemplates. You can read all about them [on the microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

In your case you want to declare a separate template for each type you're trying to display:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:A}">
     <TextBlock Text="This object is type A">
 </DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:B}">
     <TextBlock Text="This object is type B">
 </DataTemplate>
```

...and so on. This is typically done in the Resources block of whatever window/user control that this code appears on, although it can also be declared in the App.xaml resources block etc.

DataTemplates are used by any WPF control that is able to bind to data in some way. Take `Button`, for example....the overall look of the button including the border and how it behaves to mouse-over etc is dictated by its ControlTemplate (which you can also override yourself of course). But at some point in the XAML it has to render the actual data that you've assigned to its "Content" property, and if you were to look at the ControlTemplate for Button you'd find something like this buried inside it:

```
<ContentPresenter />
```

This effectively says "ok, this is where my actual data should be rendered, but instead of declaring it specifically here I want you to refer to the object's corresponding DataTemplate instead". In this way you can create a top-level button style using a single ControlTemplate, but you can then specify multiple DataTemplates for each of the types of things that you'll render inside it.

Lots of controls use DataTemplate, including things like ListBox etc where each element in the list can be given a different graphical representation based on its type. Going back to your own specific problem, if you just want to render the data itself without any bells and whistles etc around it then just use a `ContentControl`:

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyModel}" />
```

So `MyModel` should be a property of type `model` that's in your view model layer (or whatever else you've set the DataContext to). Assigning that property to be an instance of type A, B or C will cause the ContentControl to be populated with an instance of whatever you've declared in its DataTemplate.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for taking the time to write such a nice reply. Second, this sounds really super easy. I'll have to test it and get back to you with my results :D

Comment: EXCELLENT. Fits right into my needs. To be honest I started implementing my proposed solution with a programmatically generated GUI. Today I worked on doing exactly the same thing with DataTemplates. I ended up to exactly the same result. I'm not sure if its more efficient or not. FOR SURE it provides re-usable code wherever I need it in the future. I got only one concern. I'm not sure how to handle common properties derived from the base class. For now I have to copy-paste them on every data template. I'm not sure if this is because of the abstract nature of the base model class.

Comment: That can be done by placing the common elements (i.e. those that bind to your `model` class) into their own ControlTemplate. Then you just insert that template into your DataTemplates with `<Control Template="{StaticResource YourControlTemplate}" />`

Comment: This is exactly the solution I found on the net on handling common templates and again works like a charm. Thanks again so much, case solved.